# Get notified when UIImage *actually* updates

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When loading large images to a UIImage's setImage method, it can sometimes take a few seconds for the UI to update. Is there anyway to get notified of when the image is actually displayed to the user?

Comment: How large of an image are we talking? What thread are you calling `-setImage:` on? How are you loading the image (`-[UIImage imageNamed:]`, downloading from network, etc.)?

Comment: Nope, all local storage (loaded using imageWithUrl:) but they are animated gifs, so they can get to be a few megabytes in size. The UI update and image loading is in the main thread.

Comment: Are you loading the image and setting it to a UIImageView in the same line? Can you post the code snippet that you use to both load the image and set it visible?

Comment: Also, I don't see a method called `+imageWithURL:` on UIImage. Can you be a little more precise about what exactly you're calling?